# AngularJs redirecting to signin route while trying to access signup route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, location

When I run my application it's redirect automatically to `/signin` and when I try to go page `/signup` can't redirect.
I want to check with `next` when have  path `http://localhost:9000/signup` to location to `/signup` but no working any idea ?

**user.service.js:**

```js
angular.module('crud').service('User', function($sails) {

  return {
    isLoggedIn: function() {

      this.getUser();

    },
    setUser: function(aUser) {
      localStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(aUser));
    },

    getUser: function() {
      return localStorage.getItem('User');
      //console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
    }
  }

});
```

**APP.js:**

```js
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $log, User) {

      $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current, jwtHelper) {

        if (!User.isLoggedIn()) {
          $location.path("/signin");
        } else if (next === "http://localhost:9000/signup") {
          $location.path("/signup");
        }
      });
```

Comment: what it display when you add console.log(next); right before if(!User.isLoggedIn()){...

Comment: it's display path clicking

Comment: is the path pattern like "http://localhost:9000/signup" or "http://localhost:9000/#/signup"

show me one of the path value

Answer (score 0):

Every time user tries to sign up, you're redirecting the user to sign in. Update the condition to not interrupt routing to `signup` and `signin`:

```js
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $log, User) {
      $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current, jwtHelper) {
        var allowed = ["http://localhost:9000/signup",
          "http://localhost:9000/signin"
        ]
        if (allowed.indexOf(next) < 0 && !User.isLoggedIn()) {
          $location.path("/signin");
        }
      });
```